# How to dynamically resize a group of images

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I've cut a big image into pieces that are more manageable and put them together so the big image is shown again. I've done this since I wanted each of the individual pieces to have a different hyper-link. Now I'm seeing that when I resize the images the display is broken into pieces. I've used a  in order to put them all together but unfortunately this does not solves the problem. How can I resize the images dynamically without breaking the whole thing into pieces.

Ps: Is there any option to make the pieces act as one large image using div

Comment: You should consider keeping the image whole and just mapping links to different locations on the image.

Comment: I second using an image map on a single image.

Comment: I used mapping before but when I resize the image to make it mobile friendly, the links in mapping don't adjust to the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the CSS mapping on an image, instead of cutting the image to pieces ?

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp
- http://www.neopets.com/~Kacizilla

Update: 
 For Responsive image maps there are a couple of options - JS / SVG and it still is possible with pure CSS:

- JQuery Plugin - http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html
- JavaScript: http://www.andensolutions.com/blog/responsiveImagePaths
- SVG: http://demosthenes.info/blog/760/Create-A-Responsive-Imagemap-With-SVG
- Pure CSS: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-responsive-image-map.html

Update 2:

Pure CSS method:

Its not really a map, but it follows nearly the same logic:

You have an image within a **Relative positioned** container:

```
<div class="imageMap">
   <img src="yourimage.png" style="position: relative;"> 
   <a href="yourURL" class="yourLink"></a>
</div>
```

Your links are actually **Absolutely** positioned  tags, that have: **top,left** (or any other combination) + **width**, and **height**. Just make sure you use **percentages**, so it can stay responsive.

```
.yourLink  {
   position: absolute;
   left: 11%;
   top: 5%;
   width: 25%;
   height: 34%;
}
```

and there is also a JS based image map editor: http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/index

Comment: I used mapping. But when I resize the image to make it mobile friendly, the links in mapping don't adjust to the image.

Comment: I have updated the answer a bit with responsive image map options.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way to see the code for the Pure CSS example?

Comment: I will update the answer again, to be able to post code.